# Find minimum in specific column and the corresponding row number in a matrix

Tags: matrix, stata, minimum

I'm trying to find a way to look for the minimum in a specific (always the same) column of a matrix in Stata, and then have it give me the row number of the corresponding element.

Comment: What code did you try? Is this, as implied, a Stata matrix rather than a dataset?

Comment: Yes, it is Stata matrix. I use the `varsoc` command and then use `matrix list r(stats)` to get the results as a matrix. I'm not sure how to continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some technique. Note that in general the minimum or maximum in a column might occur in one or more rows.

```
. webuse lutkepohl2
(Quarterly SA West German macro data, Bil DM, from Lutkepohl 1993 Table E.1)

. varsoc dln_inv dln_inc dln_consump

   Selection-order criteria
   Sample:  1961q2 - 1982q4                     Number of obs      =        87
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |lag |    LL      LR      df    p      FPE       AIC      HQIC      SBIC    |
  |----+----------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  0 |  696.398                      2.4e-11  -15.9402  -15.9059  -15.8552* |
  |  1 |  711.682  30.568    9  0.000  2.1e-11  -16.0846  -15.9477* -15.7445  |
  |  2 |  724.696  26.028    9  0.002  1.9e-11* -16.1769* -15.9372  -15.5817  |
  |  3 |  729.124  8.8557    9  0.451  2.1e-11  -16.0718  -15.7294  -15.2215  |
  |  4 |  738.353  18.458*   9  0.030  2.1e-11  -16.0771   -15.632  -14.9717  |
  +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   Endogenous:  dln_inv dln_inc dln_consump
    Exogenous:  _cons

. matrix li r(stats)

r(stats)[5,9]
           lag          LL          LR          df           p         FPE
r1           0   696.39806          .b          .b          .b   2.398e-11
r2           1   711.68216   30.568191           9   .00035098   2.076e-11
r3           2   724.69624    26.02817           9   .00202142   1.894e-11
r4           3   729.12407   8.8556522           9   .45070419   2.109e-11
r1           4   738.35331   18.458484           9   .03021188   2.105e-11

           AIC        HQIC        SBIC
r1  -15.940185  -15.905946  -15.855154
r2  -16.084647  -15.947689  -15.744522
r3  -16.176925  -15.937249  -15.581706
r4  -16.071818  -15.729423  -15.221505
r1  -16.077088  -15.631974  -14.971681

. mata
------------------------------------------------- mata (type end to exit) -----
: stats = st_matrix("r(stats)")

: select((1::rows(stats)), (stats[,7] :== colmax(stats[,7])))
  1

: select((1::rows(stats)), (stats[,9] :== colmax(stats[,9])))
  5
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much! However I never got it to work in the way I need it to. I now have found a way to program what I need to do, but it just won't work in a loop. I ws wondering if you could maybe give me advice on what to change?

Answer (score 0):

Her is what I have so far. I am aware that there is probably a better way to code it, but thats all I can do right now.

```
foreach c of local gracauseloop {
varsoc rppi_chst `c' , maxlag(5)
matrix A = r(stats)
svmat A, name(col)
drop lag LL LR df p FPE AIC HQIC
egen minSB = min (SBIC)
egen lags = fill(0 1 2 3 4 5)
gen varlag = lags if minSB == SBIC
egen lag = total(varlag)
local vlag  "lag"
var rppi_chst `c' , lags(1/`vlag')
vargranger
clear matrix
drop SBIC minSB lags varlag lag
}
```

Comment: Not self-contained or reproducible. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve